# If Else Statement Not Returning Right Value

Tags: java, parsing, indexing, substring

I am trying to check if a playlist is simple or master by an index value. My problem is when I put the (True) URL it still returns a false statement "This is a simple Playlist".

Any tips on how I can fix this ?

```
String output = getPlaylistUrl(input);
String mediaRecord = output.substring(399);
String lastRecord = "gear4/prog_index.m3u8";
if (mediaRecord == lastRecord) {
    System.out.println("This is a master playlist");
} else {
    System.out.println("This is a simple playlist");
}
```

Comment: mediaRecord probably indeed is not `"gear4/prog_index.m3u8"` - indeed `substring(399)` seems _difficult_.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to correct the error in it. I rolled it back.

Comment: Sorry keep getting notifications that it's a duplicate question when I feel like it's different.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, strings can not be compared for equality using `==`, because `==` compares two instances, not the content. So unless s1 and s2 are actually the same instance, `s1 == s2` will never return `true`.

You need to use `equals(...)` to compare two strings for equality.

```
if (mediaRecord.equals(lastRecord) { ... }
```

Comment: How can a perfectly correct answer be downvoted?

Comment: 'string comparisons using == always fail' well that's unecessarily broad...

Comment: @daniu What do you mean? You can not compare two strings for equality using == in Java.

Comment: == will still check that the Strings are the same object. Not the same as checking that they have the same contents, but it won't necessary always fail (as daniu said).

Comment: `if ("a" == "a") System.out.println("true")` prints `true` for me, so the comparison doesn't _always_ fail. Same for `String a = "a"; System.out.println(a == "a")`, but that's becoming dangerous terrain.

Comment: I updated the answer anyways, but I still do not see why this should be a proper reason for a downvote.

Comment: @daniu come on... that may not be completely accurate, but did not warrant a downvote...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am still getting the Simple Playlist as a return value. I literally checked the index of the value I am comparing before this so I am confused why this may be happening.

Comment: Did you also debug to make sure that `mediaRecord` and `lastRecord` actually do contain the same text (including all whitespace, etc.)?

Comment: Just checked thank you. MediaRecord is returning every record for some reason.

Comment: Thanks a ton I got it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare Strings you need to use .equals and not ==. Using == compares references and not values